# Storing PHP in a database

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

If I had a menubar that was totally dynamic where you can add pages to it and remove pages from it (being stored in  database) . These pages all have content in a database , things like an article however I cant store PHP code in the database so I cant add things like dynamic tables within the page, is there any way around this or am I missing something. I am using Laravel. Feel free to ask to elaborate as I dont think this is as concise as it could be.

Comment: Yes, you could store PHP in a database and use `exec` to run it. **No, this is not a good idea at all.**

Comment: Store the page ids the user has access to in the database, not the PHP code itself

Comment: Why would you need to store a whole php code in the database? You can just store the raw text in the database and then load it into a template. You are using an MVC framework. Why are you using one if you don't know the capabilities of it?

Comment: you can store every information needed to recreate dynamic table (or whatever content you need) and have php file to do it. there is absolutely no need for storing php code in database (although it is possible)

Comment: Please don't do that. Storing PHP code in your database is almost never the right solution. You'll have to use [eval()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php) in your PHP to evaluate the PHP from a string and that is frowned upon for [several](http://dhorrigan.com/post/30395987906/is-eval-really-evil-yes-and-no) [reasons](http://www.blog.highub.com/php/php-core/php-eval-is-evil/).

Comment: I know your not meant to, I was just wondering what the alternatives were and I couldnt phrase the question well as I was frustrated. Can someone elaborate on methods of doing this without having to store the php in an actual database, I know this is a very crude image but this is what im trying to do : http://prntscr.com/5rkzzb

Comment: I dont want to start spamming but can someone help? I saw Krisztians answer but I dont see how I would do that, make the info into an array and stuff it into the database? When you take it out how do you plaace it etc..

Comment: The pages would go in the database as a template or straight HTML if they don't need any placeholders.  You would just use php to pull it out of the database, do any processing on it if you needed to, and return it.

Comment: But then I dont understand, how do I apply PHP to the code, lets say I had a table in the HTML and I want data from the database, so how would I avoid putting PHP in the database but still get data in the table from the database.

Comment: @Batzz Please, read http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/templates. See the `@foreach` and the `with()` bits, in particular.

Comment: I understand them, I'm trying to figure out something at the minute but if it doesnt work I'll come back for help.

Answer (score 0):

First of all: Saving php code into a database, or doing anything requireing eval is usually wrong code.

What you could do is make classes which renders the right dynamic view, Make an array of [anonymous](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php) functions which can instantiate the classes, and put the array keys into the database.

your code would look like this:

```
class yourrenderClassLol{
  function render(){echo"lol";}
}

$classes["yourrenderClass"]=function(){
  static $instance=NULL;
  if($instance==NULL){
      $instance=new yourrenderClassLol();
   }  

    return $instance
}

$classes["yourrenderClass"]()->render();
```